# JavaScript error when logged in

Tags: bug, internet-explorer-8

When I am logged in to any Stack Exchange site, many (all?) of the JavaScript features do not work. I am unable to view my inbox or view more comments, autosuggestions for tags do not work, and I am unable to view my question as it will finally appear while typing it. I am getting the error

```
Expected ')'
full.js
Line: 166
Char: 336
```

This error started today and does not occur on other Stack Exchange sites. I am using Internet Explorer 8 (I know, I know... I can't change it for now).

Why could this be?

For some reason, this applies on every Stack Exchange site *except* Meta Stack Overflow. Other Stack Exchange meta sites do not work.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was running in compatibility mode on Internet Explorer 8, which is, apparently, unsupported.